# Programmatic close of Foundation 6 offCanvas

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, off-canvas-menu

I want to use javascript to close an offcanvas area as the result of loading an ajax script.

The documentation says `$('#element').foundation('close', cb);` but there isn't much in the way of explanation as to what `#element` and `cb` are :/

What are `#element` and `cb`?  How would you programmatically close their example?

```
<body>
  <div class="off-canvas-wrapper">
    <div class="off-canvas-wrapper-inner" data-off-canvas-wrapper>
      <div class="off-canvas position-left" id="offCanvas" data-off-canvas>

        <!-- Close button -->
        <button class="close-button" aria-label="Close menu" type="button" data-close>
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>

        <!-- Menu -->
        <ul class="vertical menu">
          <li><a href="#">Foundation</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dot</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ZURB</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Com</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Slash</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sites</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>

      <div class="off-canvas-content" data-off-canvas-content>
        <!-- Page content -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in js with
$('#offCanvas').foundation('close');

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger close button.

```
<button id="btn-close-offcanvas" type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>


$("#btn-close-offcanvas").click();
```